# Merge more than 2 tfvars file contents

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have usecase where I have 3 tfvars files

```
1.tfvars
api_stages=[
  {
      api_id= "xxxx"
      stage="play"
  }
]

2.tfvars
api_stages=[
  {
      api_id= "yyy"
      stage="play"
  }
]

3.tfvars    
api_stages=[
  {
      api_id= "zzz"
      stage="play"
  }
]
```

and I am creating 1 single usage plan using this

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan" "usage_plan" {
  name         = var.usage_plan_name     
   throttle_settings {
    burst_limit = var.burst_limit
    rate_limit  = var.rate_limit
  }  
   
  dynamic "api_stages" {
      for_each = var.api_stages
      content {
        api_id     = api_stages.value.api_id
        stage = api_stages.value.stage      
      }
    }
}
```

And this tfvars files will be created by different users.

**Question: How can I merge this different tfvars file and attach all api_id and stages to single usage plan?**

right now when I am doing plan, it's only taking last file's value.

Comment: You need to define a merging strategy and code it there is no magic solution for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.tfvars` file processing happens before any configuration expressions are evaluated, so there is no way to do *exactly* what you asked about here: the rule for `.tfvars` files is always that the last definition of a particular variable "wins", as you've seen.

The some options that are *close* to what you want here would be:

- Define three different variables, perhaps named to indicate the three different sources that are providing these values, and then concatenate the three of them together in a [local value](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html):

  ```
  locals {
    all_api_stages = concat(
      var.a_api_stages,
      var.b_api_stages,
      var.c_api_stages,
    )
  }
  ```

  This approach would be appropriate only if there being exactly three sets of variables is a meaningful constraint for your system.
- Declare the actual stage objects inside your configuration and make the variable instead be a list of keys for them:

  ```
  variable "api_stages" {
    type = set(string)
  }

  locals {
    api_stages = {
      x = {
        api_id = "xxxx"
        stage  = "play"
      }
      y = {
        api_id = "yyyy"
        stage  = "play"
      }
      z = {
        api_id = "zzzz"
        stage  = "play"
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  You can then use `-var` when running Terraform to choose the appropriate settings, instead of using `-var-file`:

  ```
  terraform apply -var='api_stages=["x", "y"]'
  ```